# Firebase Set the Notification Title and Body to Database Value

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think this is a fairly basic question, but I have a Firebase function file with an index.js file within. I am able to trigger a push notification when the database is updated with a new value, but just need help setting the notification's title and body to the values added in the child nodes. Here is what I have so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// database tree
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/questions/{id}').onWrite(event =>{
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: //Value at /questions/{id}/question,
            body: //Value at /questions/{id}/bestAnswer,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default',
        }

    };
    return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
        if (allToken.val()){
            const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
            console.log('token? ${token}');
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response =>{
              return null;
            });
        }

        return null;
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI you're using an old version of the firebase-functions SDK.  You should be working with 1.x rather than 0.x.  The APIs have changed.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will definitely take a look at that and update, but do you know how I could do it with what I have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference any value of the created object:

```
event.val().question
event.val().bestAnswer
```

Using those you can update your notification:

```
payload.notification.title = event.val().question;
payload.notification.body = event.val().bestAnswer;
```

or

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: event.val().question,
            body: event.val().bestAnswer,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default',
        }
```